# Interfacing temperature system to moving coil

Tags: sensor, temperature, meter, non-linear

I was working on a design question (this is not homework, just personal practice). Can someone please help me get started or guide me through any worked steps please?

[image]

Comment: Would you consider a tick mark every 20 degrees to provide 10 degrees precision? (Assuming someone reading this could estimate halfway between the ticks?) Or??

Comment: Amplify the signal 20x so 100°C = 10V. Since the display scale is blank and you are asked to illustrate the display scale, draw appropriate markers every 10°C. I assume that 120° is the display arc, not full scale temperature.

Comment: @qrk thank you for the response, so the tick marks would just be every 10 degrees? Does the 120 degrees not have any relevance?

Comment: Also would the display scale just show the non-linear response incremented by 10 degrees to 120?

Comment: @kam Imagine that full scale temperature (100 C) is 120 degrees of swing. (Voltage gain of 20 to get it from the sensor.) At 20C the voltage (after voltage gain) is 4 V or 40% of the swing. So 48 degrees. Another 48 degrees are used up at the other end of the scale (from 80 C to 100 C.) So that leaves only 24 degrees for the range from 20 C to 80 C, right? Can you label the temperature scale now with degrees of swing?

Comment: @periblepsis thank you, I am following what you are saying with the 48 degrees, 24 degrees and then another 48 degrees but if I label the temperature scale now with degrees of swing (48, 24, 48) which I'm assuming you mean labelling (0,0), (48,4), (72,6) (120,10) how does this incorporate the 10 degrees of precision part? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kam Create your 120 degree arc and divide it into ticks at every 4 degrees (or 8 degrees.) Then label your ticks. See what that gives you.

Comment: @periblepsis, so I divided my 120 degree arc into ticks at every 8 degrees and labelled them but I still have the points (48,4), (72,6) (120,10) along with 13 other points, and the same shape as the non-linear response just scaled differently, is that the purpose or should it be different?

Comment: @periblepsis, so 10 degrees accuracy would be like (0, 0), (8, 0.6666666667), (16, 1.3333333333), (24,2), (32, 2.66666666670, (40, 3.3333333333)...? Please help, very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @kam Don't you think your scale would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx4jH.png)? Also, bear in mind that if this isn't a story problem (idealized) then the concept of accuracy requires NIST or DIN traceable standards. The sensor and the galvanometer alike. Precision is one thing. Accuracy another.

Comment: The accuracy in the meter reading come about only because you have compensated the scale of the meter defection in degrees/C to match that of the sensor curve.

Comment: @periblepsis, thank you so much, I finally understand!

Comment: @Nedd thank you also for clarifying accuracy!

Comment: @kam Develop a flexible imagination and keep working on it. Best wishes.

Comment: @periblepsis, would you be so kind and take a look at this question please: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/651076/330725?sem=2

Comment: @kam It's closed. Besides, why so much repeated 'gnashing of teeth' over this same example case? If it's not homework and just some example you are testing yourself about, why all this repetition and adding complications dealing with the corner transitions? If this is a practical situation (and I can't imagine how anything gives a curve like that) then talk about what's going on, for gosh sake. If it is just idea-space and nothing else, you've enough to understand the issues and there's no need to ask others to tackle it.

Comment: @periblepsis, I understand your point, actually this question was presented to me at a an interview, I found it pretty vague and hard to answer, so I was curious about the solution

Comment: @kam Without more information from those interviewing, there is no "solution." There are just possible choices. You could, as I showed you, develop a scale that reflects the sensor and use a simple voltage-gain+buffer to drive it. If you don't like the scale that results -- despite the fact that it answers the question as given -- then you need to come up with specific objections. Without the objections, no new solution can be considered. Developing a circuit that divides things up creates more problems than you can imagine. So it's likely not an option.