# Designing a digital display

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, switches, adc, comparator

I was working on a design question (this is not homework, just personal practice). So I have a temperature sensor with a non-linear response, and ideally I would like to design a digital display system with the a couple requirements.

Ideally, I want to feed in the output of this temperature sensor to an Analog to digital converter. To do this I know we have to use two compartor opamps for the two "corners" of the plot I'm not sure how this would be done, I was thinking that the first opamp that would be used should be an inverting opamp so when the voltage is below 0.2 the opamp would output a high value and then another opamp that is a non-inverting opamp for the second part so when the voltage is above 0.3 the output would be high, would this logic work?

Can someone please help me confirm this (or add on to this) or help me think another way? Thank you in advance.

The graph below shows the output of the temperature sensor.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use op-amps to convert the bent line into a straight line.

Comment: Kam - Hi, At the moment, this question seems to just repeat the answer you got to your [previous question](/q/650478), without anything more (hence a duplicate). If you have questions trying to actually *implement* the approach which was recommended & if you include your attempted schematic and explain a *specific & detailed problem*, then that could be a valid new question. Please also link to your previous question in that case, so readers can see how you use the previous help. At the moment you have asked 3 questions on the same design question, which are all quite general. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson, none of the answers or comments in this question relate to the previous one, this question has details the other one does not, and I can't make this question more specific as this is a general question that has many potential answers, I just want to know if what I'm thinking is correct

Comment: Thank you @Velvel

Comment: @kam - You said: "*I was thinking of two comparator op amp configurations to detect the two corners in the plot*" which is effectively the [answer you got to your previous question](/a/650482), so this question reads like you want ask whether that answer to your previous question is good. Ask questions about that answer *there*. Note that the first comment you got *here* was a hint suggesting the same answer *again*! It shows that this question reads like your previous one. We try to avoid site members spending (wasting) time, repeating previous effort on overlapping & duplicate questions.

Comment: We recommend you ask [specific](/help/how-to-ask) questions. As you have seen on your previous question, there is a closure reason of "needs focus" (previously called "too broad") when site members believe it isn't asking one *specific* question. We're trying to help you to avoid that. "*this is a general question that has many potential answers*" That is the first time you have explained that you realise this. General questions are typically a poor fit here, as there is no objective right answer. This site isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. We need a *specific* Q to help best. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend you remove ALL fluff, and ask one very specific question. This question with all of the fluff is too broad, which typically doesn't attract good answers. I'd recommend you research "opamp gain circuit" and "opamp comparator circuit". Show us what you understood and ask a very specific question.

Comment: @SamGibson, I have changed the question to be more specific, can this question be open again?

Comment: @Velvel can you help with the improved question?